# How to add metadata to forms in php?

Tags: php

In my html forms I have to add `<input name='userID' value='<?php echo $_SESSION[' userID'];?>' style=' display:none;'>` to add that kind of data to my forms and I kinda think that's a bit rediculous. How do I add metadata like that properly?

Comment: you have to just use <input type='hidden' name='tag_name' value='value' />

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to send metadata through hidden keys, but why are you sending a session data, if on next page you can get it by the same way?

Or maybe you send it to another server? If that - you must send data more carefully and must check if all sended data  delivered right way - for example make data hash and check it on delivery side:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $_SESSION['user_id'] . $somevalue . $somevalue . $salt);
<input type='hidden' name='hash_value' value='{$hash}' />
```

but, again, it does not make sense to send session data, if you can get them on the next page through $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Sorry, selection of example was poor. Thanks though!